# Can't make the grid with 100% height

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, native-base

[image]

I am trying to remove free space (marginBottom) on the screen which you see but it seems a bug.I am using Native-Base with expo. I tried some solutions but all of them brought this result. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, ImageBackground, StatusBar, Platform, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Content, View, Icon, Text } from "native-base";
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

let categoriesCol1 = [{ title: "Lorem ipsum" }, { title: "Lorem ipsum" }, { title: "Lorem ipsum" },]
let categoriesCol2 = [{ title: "Lorem ipsum" }, { title: "Lorem ipsum" }, { title: "Lorem ipsum" },]
let win = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.img} source={require("./cover.jpg")}>
        <Content style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Grid style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Row >
              <Col style={styles.col}>
                {categoriesCol1.map((item, idx) => {
                  return <SectionContainer key={idx} item={item} />;
                })}
              </Col>
              <Col style={styles.col}>
                {categoriesCol2.map((item, idx) => {
                  return <SectionContainer key={idx} item={item} />;
                })}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Content>

      </ImageBackground >
    );
  }
}

const SectionContainer = ({ item, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Row onPress={() => console.warn("Item selected")
    }>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#ffffff", flex: 1 }}>
        <Icon active name={"home"} style={styles.icon} />
        <Text style={styles.text}> {item.title} </Text>
      </View>
    </Row >

  );
};


const styles = {
  col: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
  },
  icon: {
    marginTop: 50,
    color: "#ffffff",
    fontWeight: '900',
    fontSize: 50
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 28,
    color: '#ffffff',
    marginBottom: 50

  }
}
```

What is wrong on this code? How can I remove that free space from the bottom of the screen and make the grid with 100% height?

Comment: whether any padding or margin is there around the images?

Comment: Nope. There is not.

Comment: can you try adding `width:100%` too to the style `img`

Comment: Image is full height this issue is connected with grid not with background image